# Referencing mscorlib 4.0.0.0 from .NET Core 1.0 class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, class-library

I have a .NET Core 1.0 class library which targets .NET 4.6.1 and references the .NET Standard Library 1.6.0 and Identity Framework 2.2.1

**project.json**

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "2.2.1",
        "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {
            "imports": [
                "net461"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In my project I'm just creating the identity models, which extend the base Identity Framework models (User, Role etc). When I try to compile, this happens...

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you add a reference to mscorlib v4.0.0.0?

Comment: @Tim, I'm assuming not, as I'm not sure how I would do that in a .NET Core class library

Comment: Probably the same way other dependencies are added?  In the project.json file?  I'm not 100% sure as I haven't played with .NET Core 1.0 a whole lot yet.

Comment: @Tim, there doesn't appear to be an "mscorlib" reference available in that respect.

Comment: Not even something like "mscorlib": "4.0.0.0" under dependencies?

Comment: @Tim, nope not even something like that.

Comment: Might not be doable - https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbbb0b2d-5f4d-4962-b6e7-7e9e017d321d/adding-vbnet-dll-as-reference-to-aspnet-core-1-project?forum=Offtopic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems with your project file here, one simple to fix, one impossible to fix ;)

- Your project **does not** target `net461` and `netstandard1.6`. What your project.json says is: Build target for `netstandard1.6` and lie to NuGet and claim you are `net461` (that lying is what `import` does ... do not believe me, look it up ;)). And since your project.json lied to NuGet, you where able to add `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`. Adding `net461` and `netstandard1.6` in parallel will not help you either because you cannot add the dependency then.
- The NuGet dependency `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` is released in 2015 and **based on the .NET Framework (mscorlib based)** and not on .NET Standard / .NET Core (System.Runtime based). The lying does not help about the fact that the dependency is based on `mscorlib` and not `System.Runtime`.

What you could try, is targeting (correctly) in parallel `net461` and `netstandard1.6` and try to do a parallel implementation with `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` respectively using #ifdefs. However, how useful the result would be, I have no idea for what the resulting library would be used ;)

Comment: Spectacular answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Microsoft has a nuget package that can help.  I don't know the specifics of how it works but it resolved my dependency issues:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility/

Or simply run this in the package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility -Version 1.0.1
```

edit:
This was added to a .net core 1.1 project.

Comment: Thank you Man. Work like a charm