# Invoking Roslyn from code with .NET Core on OSX: "No assembly containing System.Object was found"

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-core, roslyn

I'm trying to invoke Roslyn from C# in .NET Core on OSX.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cscArgs = CSharpCommandLineParser.Default.Parse(
            new[] { "/target:Library" },
            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
            "/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/"
        );
        var refs = cscArgs.MetadataReferences.Select(x => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(x.Reference, x.Properties));

        foreach (var r in refs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.FilePath);
        }

        var trees = new[]
        {
            CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("class Foo {}", cscArgs.ParseOptions)
        };

        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(cscArgs.CompilationName, trees, refs, cscArgs.CompilationOptions);

        using (var peStream = File.OpenWrite("test.dll"))
        {
            var emitResult = compilation.Emit(peStream, null, null, null, cscArgs.ManifestResources, cscArgs.EmitOptions);

            foreach (var d in emitResult.Diagnostics)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, (`test.dll` remains empty and) the `WriteLine`s print out one `MetadataReference` followed by a warning and two compilation errors:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/mscorlib.dll
warning CS8021: No value for RuntimeMetadataVersion found. No assembly containing System.Object was found nor was a value for RuntimeMetadataVersion specified through options.
(2,31): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
(2,31): error CS1729: 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

So it looks like the `Compilation` isn't picking up the `mscorlib` reference. The DLL does indeed exist in the cited location.

```
$ ls /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/mscorlib.dll
/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/mscorlib.dll
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I convince Roslyn to pick up the `mscorlib` DLL?

Comment: Similar issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943899/net-core-cs0012-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to compile an assembly for .NET Core, `System.Object` is defined in `System.Runtime`, not mscorlib.<sup>1</sup> Also, when compiling for .NET Core, the compilers usually use reference assemblies, not the actual runtime binaries.

So, **short answer**: create MetadataReference for System.Runtime.dll.

```cs
var nuget = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + "/.nuget/packages";
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(nuget + "/system.runtime/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Runtime.dll")
```

**Longer answer**

Chances are good you'll want more than just System.Runtime, though. An easier way to see which libraries are being referenced is to inspect the compilation of your own application. To see this, add a package reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` and inspect all the libraries used to compile and app.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="2.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```cs
var references = from l in DependencyContext.Default.CompileLibraries
                 from r in l.ResolveReferencePaths()
                 select MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(r);

foreach (var r in references)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.FilePath);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.object, at the very bottom of the page.