# Cannot install `mscorlib` in .Net Core app

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, mscorlib

I am trying to consume a `.net 4.6.1 package` into `.net core app`. I am successful in downloading the nuget package. But while trying to register the dependencies as services it is throwing error.

```
services.AddTransient<IJobSchedulerIntegrator, JobSchedulerIntegrator>(); //throwing error that mscorlib needs to be installed
```

**Error**

```
The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

[image]

As the class `JobSchedulerIntegrator` is inheriting `object`. It needs `mscorlib`. But i cannot install `mscorlib` into `.net core` app.

Is there anyway i can fix this problem.

**Project.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    "API.Framework.Integrators.JobScheduler": "1.0.0",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "Serilog": "2.0.0",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.Literate": "2.0.0",
    "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.1.0",
    "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.2.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "net461",
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net452+win81"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your project.json file?

Comment: @Kalten, added project.json content.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646466/referencing-mscorlib-4-0-0-0-from-net-core-1-0-class-library/38688430#38688430

Comment: Last hope for you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility/

Comment: @Thomas I tried this already. Didn't work.  I think .net core is stil in it's infancy.  May b i should wait for few more releases before implementing it.

Comment: Rebasing business logic code to System.Runtime is not that big effort.

Answer (score 1):

The imports section is more a hack than a recommendation. That allow you to use a nuget package that not target explicitly a the current framework.

If the content of the package doesn't contains compatible dll, that can't work.
You should replace the target framework `netcoreapp1.0` by any other compatible one (like `NET46`) and remove `imports`.

Comment: Thanks Kalten, But if i change the target framework to NET46 then the app is not said to be a .net core app. I think i am looking for a few more suggestions.